# class not found even when it exits on Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm making my first application using Yii and I have the next code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();
    $singUp = new \frontend\models\SingupForm;
    if ($singUp->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $singUp->save()) {
        $model = ModelName::findOne(['id' => $singUP->id]);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'singUp' => $singUp
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I'm having the next error message when I try to go to that method:

> Class 'frontend\models\SingupForm' not found

But I have the file saved on the directory as it is showed in the screenshot I attached. Additionally I added all the models folder of the Frontend on the controller I am using:

```
use Yii;
use \frontend\models;
use common\models\User;
use backend\models\search\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\PermissionHelpers;
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBFKG.png)

Comment: You have a typo. The class is SignupForm not SingupForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code.

Please Change **frontend\models\SingupForm** to **frontend\models\SignupForm**.